# Createjs events - "mouseleave" works but "click" doesn't

Tags: javascript, createjs, easeljs

I'm using nodejs with socket. This is my code on the frontend.

```
let socket = io.connect();

function init() {
    let stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas");
    stage.enableMouseOver(20);
    stage.on("mouseleave", function (event) {
        console.log("mouseleave");
    });
    stage.on("click", function (event) {
        console.log("click");
    });
    stage.update();
}
```

I see "mouseleave" logging on the console when I move the cursor out of the canvas. But never see "click" when I click. I also tried "mousedown" but it also doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The "click" event only fires when content on the stage is clicked. The event will bubble up, and be dispatched from the stage. If you click empty space, there is no event.

Instead, use the "stage" mouse events.

```
stage.on("stagemousedown", function (event) {
    console.log("mousedown");
});

stage.on("stagemouseup", function (event) {
    console.log("click");
});
```

[Link to documentation](https://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Stage.html#event_stagemousedown)

Comment: Yes, that seems to work. But now I have a queue with preloadjs loading images and I add them to an array. After everything is loaded I do assets["idOfTheImage"].on("click", function (event) ... ) and it doesn't work. Could you help?

Comment: Can you update your question with more code? A number of things can cause click events to work. Are there any errors in your console? What is the `assets` object? Cheers!